Wordpress - Remove entry content block altogether
I want to use ACF in Wordpress to build my pages, and so I want to get rid of the "entry-content" field completely in the block editor. What is the best way to go about this?
I have looked online for solutions but cannot find what I'm looking for: most 'solutions' I found are saying to simply use display: none, but that doesn't help me in this case because I want to remove the entire field from the editor.

Solved using the following code in functions.php:
add_action( 'init', function() {
    remove_post_type_support( 'page', 'editor' );
}, 99);

